# How do I update a variant price using shopify gem in rails 3.2.2?

Tags: shopify

Rails 3.2.2 app, using the most recent shopify gem on github.

I've looked at other threads on the shopify google group that suggested switching 
ShopifyAPI::Base to use xml, but that had no effect. 
Simple script, updates a product's variant prices. This used to work, 
not sure when it stopped working, but script is identical to the old 
working version.

Essentially, if I set a variant price and compare_at_price, and then 
save, shopify does not reflect a change. The method returns true, 
however. Originally, the script simply called product.save at the end, 
but I've also tried saving the variants individually and no luck. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should post the raw request and response you are seeing.

Comment: It may be a problem with ActiveResource and the Shopify Gem.  Try using an older version of the shopify gem and see if that helps.

Comment: Any tips on which particular version I should try? Where do I find info on how to log the raw request from a rails console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Shopify, which has now been fixed.

It affected product updates through the API for shops that had inventory management enabled.

Please retest and confirm that it has been fixed.

Comment: Dylan, thanks for following up on this. I'll come back and accept the answer as soon as I have a moment to confirm.

Comment: Using the 3.0.1 release of the shopify_api gem, and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

If you provide us with a request id then we could lookup the request in our logs.  You can obtain the request id using the following code just after save that isn't working.

`ShopifyAPI::Base.connection.response['x-request-id']`

What I can tell you is that:

- You shouldn't need to use xml format (JSON tends to be faster)
- You should be able to save changes on a variant or product

Comment: Just ran it again to make sure I had the proper request ID, here it is: c8f44f83455013c4b252e19fbbeac244

Comment: Were you able to glean anything from the request ID?

Comment: I don't see any reason why the price wouldn't have been set. How did you check the resulting price and compare_at_price? Did you just check the storefront (e.g. as a customer)? Because those pages are cached.

Comment: I checked through the console: fetched the product through the shopify API, and printed out the variants. After setting a compare_at_price and price, compare_at_price remained nil and the price was unchanged.

Comment: Could you reproduce it with a test shop, save the request ID again, then not change the product afterwards to I can inspect the result?

Comment: [Another user encountered the same bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962321/can-not-update-the-variant-price-using-the-shopifyapi): request_id 7d995f6f6ed3bf515e69a1640f27f44a, noticed that the product's updated_at time changed, but the the variant's stayed the same (along with the price not changing), yet these changes are done in a transaction. The same price update on another shop from that user updated the variant properly. I'm still trying to determine the conditions are needed to reproduce this bug.

Comment: Thanks. I've read those threads. Want to make sure I understand: we need to wait for activeResource to get an update or downgrade activeResource to work around the problem?

Comment: I will push a fix out soon for the updating products in Shopify, it affects shops that are using inventory management. Fetching products then updating variants is a bug in ActiveResource that can worked around with a [shopify_api patch](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/pull/30).  Fetching variants then saving modifications should currently work.