# Can not update the Variant Price using the ShopifyAPI

Tags: shopify

I am facing a problem - can not update the price of the variant using the ShopifyAPI..

while updating the price of the variant, it is giving the error

> @remote_errors=#<\ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid: Failed.  Response code = 422.  Response message = Unprocessable Entity.>, @validation_context=nil, @errors=#<\ActiveResource::Errors:0x000000029eb1d0 ...>>, @messages={:base=>["Options are not unique"]}

'\' after '<' is required to show the error, otherwise stack overflow is hiding the error.

as required on another question
on production store, the request id is "38f5c3b3b7bdf4433724a845c6df4571"
on test store, the request id is "6050f165586b631e81b840dc0e1e6807"

## More Findings

variant price change on test store

```
p = ShopifyAPI::Product.last  
v = p.variants.first  
v.price = "8.00"  
v.save
```

initial price of variant = "9.00"
returns **false, with error** @messages={:base=>["Options are not unique"]}
request id 978ad18483f40ff3946df18df0a9d1d8
.
.

variant price change on live store

```
p = ShopifyAPI::Product.first  
p.variants[0].price = "24.65"  
p.save
```

initial price of variant = "25.65"
return **true, but price is not changed**
request id a9a798b631e3dd10fc81b723f2883af1
.
.

variant price change through product on test store

```
p = ShopifyAPI::Product.first  
p.variants[0].price = "8.00"  
p.save
```

initial price of variant = "7.00"
return **true and price is updated**
request id 7d995f6f6ed3bf515e69a1640f27f44a
.
.

variant price change through product on live store

```
p = ShopifyAPI::Product.last  
v = p.variants.first  
v.price = "4.00"  
v.save
```

initial price of variant = "3.00"
returns **false, with error** @messages={:base=>["Options are not unique"]}
request id c6aaa5b65576eb4ec0d89715d25b787e

Comment: See the question [How do I update a variant price using shopify gem in rails 3.2.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924734/how-do-i-update-a-variant-price-using-shopify-gem-in-rails-3-2-2) for information about the product save returning true but not updating the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in ActiveResource 3.1+.

I have opened an [ActiveResource pull request](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/pull/30), but I am still awaiting a response at the moment.

I have [committed a workaround](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/commit/0e67bfc6c946a2b4de454028c807aff24ff2bc9b) for this bug in shopify_api v3.0.1, so upgrading this gem will fix this issue for you issue.

Comment: ok this works, but with a workaround. I am using shopify_app 3.0.1 and that still depends on shopify_api 3.0.0. Have modified locally and tested and it is working fine. I have sent a [pull request](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/pull/20) on shopify_app. please see so that I can upgrade the gem on production environment

Comment: Thanks, I merged your pull request and made a new release with it.

Answer (score 3):

```
@messages={:base=>["Options are not unique"]}
```

That's your problem. Looking at the logs you're using `POST` to submit the request, which is used for creating new objects. Shopify is recognizing that there's already a variant with the specified options and refusing to create a new one.

If you use `PUT` as your HTTP method instead, Shopify will correctly interpret this as an update and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks David, this makes sense. but I could not find out how to send PUT request using the ShopifyAPI. I am fetching the collection, getting the products in the collection (products = collection.products) and then variants (variants = products[0].variants). now loop over the variants (variant = variants[0]), update the price (variant.price = "xxxx") and saving it (variant.save). Since the object is already there, ShopifyAPI should automatically fire "put" request. Am i missing something?

Comment: This is a legitimate bug in the shopify_api gem.  `ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:first).variants.first.new_record?` => true, so calling save on that record will result in a `POST` request, which will try to create a new variant. I created a [shopify_api issue](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/issues/28) for this bug.

Comment: Please see the shopify_api issue that I linked to in my previous comment for news. This is an upstream bug in ActiveResource 3.1+, which I have created a [pull request to fix in ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/pull/30).  Please don't respond here on updates to the link issues.